# What is the different between openshift deploymentconfig and kubernetes deployment

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, openshift-origin

After far as I know:

- deploymentconfig → replicationcontroller → pod

vs.

- deployment → replicaset → pod

Otherwise, do these two resources have additional differences?

The more detail the better.

Answer (score 96):

A [DeploymentConfig](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.9/dev_guide/deployments/how_deployments_work.html) (DC) in OpenShift is more or less equivalent to a Kubernetes `Deployment`, nowadays. Main difference (besides that one is using `ReplicationController` and the other using `ReplicaSet` as you rightly pointed out) is that

1. there are a few things you can do with a `DeploymentConfig` (around triggers) that you can't do with a `Deployment`.
2. `DeploymentConfig`'s are first-class citizens in the Web console.

The reason `DeploymentConfig`'s exist is because we (Red Hat) are innovating. In other words: `DeploymentConfig`'s predate `Deployment`'s and while we're always trying to propose these innovations upstream, they are not always accepted by the community as is. For example, in the case of RBAC, the stuff we had in OpenShift was accepted upstream and that's why you have the same RBAC resources etc. now in OpenShift and Kubernetes. With `DeploymentConfig`'s that was not the case. Over time one would expect that `DeploymentConfig`'s are phased out in favor of `Deployment`'s but I can't give you a timeline. If portability is your primary concern, I'd say, use `Deployment`'s.

Comment: Great explanation. Thanks. Are there any updates on that topic in 2022 (= 4 years later)?

Comment: DeploymentConfig is being deprecated with OpenShift 4.14
Feature development of DeploymentConfigs will be deprecated in OpenShift Container Platform 4.14.

As far as I know deprecated features remain around for 3 releases before they are removed so 4.18 I think DC will be gone.

Comment: Finally. Upstream contribs?

Answer (score 12):

As on version 4.6, as correctly predicted by @Michael Hausenblas, deplomentConfigs are no longer recommended by Openshift unless necessary. Apart for the points mentioned above, below are the differences -
[Deployment vs Deployment Config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CjrTA.png)

As the deployment configs uses the deployer pods underneath, it supports features like pausing midway and faster rollouts. More in details description can be found on [official documentation](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.6/applications/deployments/what-deployments-are.html).

Comment: very important information, tnx!